# CorePlot Axes expandRangeByFactor not working correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-plot

I am trying to use Scatter Graph in one of my project using the CorePlot library. I was able to achieve a good result from it as well but something went wrong, and I am sure that I have nothing to do with because I have not changed the code after that. This is how the plot is looking now:
[image]

and the `expandRangeByFactor` values that I am setting are:

```
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(350.3f)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(8.3f)];
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
```

I have no idea what is happening wrong here because by looking at the values, it should not be like this.
Need urgent help on this.

Comment: What were the ranges before? What were you expecting?

Comment: I had set range for x as 0.3 and for that of y, 4.7.

Comment: What were the final ranges? What were you expecting? As far as I know, the [`-expandRangeByFactor:`](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_mutable_plot_range.html#ae006c95556504e72611d50b1b165d814) method works as designed.

Comment: actually, it works fine starts messing up with bigger number of plots.

Comment: There is one problem that I have detected and I am not sure how to tackle it. The `expandRangeByFactor` shows different type of graph for the different number of plots. If the number of plots are bigger, the graph is congested into smaller units but if the number is small, it gets very difficult to view because the difference is very huge in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-expandRangeByFactor:` method multiplies the length of the range by the given factor. It adjusts the range location to keep the center of the range in the same place. You are using rather large factors. For example, if your starting x-range has a length of one day, the expanded range will be almost one year long.

Comment: I know what you are saying but as you can see I am putting my interval along x-axis to be an hour and as per my initial values set to be 0.3. How should I handle it?

Comment: How do I decrease the distance between the minorTicks?

Comment: Either increase the `minorTicksPerInterval` to make more minor ticks or increase the length of the plot range to compress more data values into the plot area.